# In Bulk Rename Utility, how can I lengthen list of files?

Tags: rename, bulk

In Bulk Rename Utility, how can I lengthen the list of files?

[image]

Comment: What is "bulk rename utility"?

Comment: [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is a free-for-personal use Windows application to rename files and folder in large groups. It has a good amount of options for renaming a given set of items in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to resize this window manually (at least vertically). It seems to be set as a fraction of the total window size so as to not override the renaming options in the lower portion of the pane.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Bulk Rename Utility, version 3.3.1, it is possible to expand the file list with F9, or using the expand button, or also partly expand with Ctrl+F9.