# In Bulk Rename Utility, how can I delete text in middle?

Tags: rename

Pls see screen shot beneath. [You can't see it now](https://superuser.com/q/1483708/1022717), but there are seven files with "Copy" in middle.

[image]

Comment: What is "bulk rename utility"?

Comment: Use the replace box and dont put anything in the with box, put Copy in the replace box and leave the with box empty.

Comment: @Mawg [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is a free-for-personal use Windows application to rename files and folder in large groups. It has a good amount of options for renaming a given set of items in a sensible way.

Comment: It would have helped if the OP had added a link in both of her questions about this app. Thanks (and upvote) for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the simple answer is to use `Copy` (that is, the word "Copy" followed by a blank space) in `Replace (3)`:

*ex. Replace - Copy Followed By A Space*:

[image: Bulk Rename Utility - Screenshot]

**Notes**

- You cannot see the space after "Copy" in the screenshot above, but it is there. =)
- You will want to have all the files you wish to rename selected (otherwise, you will need to rename them one at a time).
- Use `Rename` in the lower right corner to actually rename the files once the new file name(s) (in green) appear correctly.